# Arrays sort method behavior

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, sorting

I'm reading the book "Java SE 8 for the really impatient", in the first chapter I came across with the next exercise question:

> Is the comparator code in the Arrays.sort method called in the same thread as the call to sort or a different thread?

I've searched the javadoc for the Arrays.sort overloading which takes a Comparator argument but it doesn't specify anything about threads. 
I assume that for performance reasons that code could be executed in another thread, but it is just a guess.

Comment: Its called on the same thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always test it by logging the `id` of `Thread.currentThread()`.

Add something this just before calling `sort()` and in your `compare()` method.

```
logger.debug("Thread # " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
```

Answer (score 4):

Imagine you have code to get the largest element in an array:

```
int[] array = new int[] {.........};
/// Few/many lines of code between...
Arrays.sort(array);
int largest = array[array.length - 1];
```

If sorting were spawned in another thread, you'd have a race condition -- would you sort the array first, or would `largest` get assigned to first? You could avoid that problem by locking `array`, but what happens if the code you're running in already locked `array`? You can block the original thread using `join()`, but then you've pretty much defeated the purpose of spawning another thread, as your code would act exactly the same way as if there were no additional thread spawned.

For `Arrays#sort()`, the sorting takes place in the original thread, as there really isn't much point in spawning another thread. Your thread will block until the sorting is complete, just like for any other piece of code.

The closest thing to spawning another thread to sort in is the [`Arrays#parallelSort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelSort-T%3aA-) method introduced in Java 8. This still acts pretty much the same as the regular `Arrays#sort()`, as it blocks your current thread until the sorting is done, but there are threads spawned in the background to help sort the array. For larger datasets, I'd expect an improvement of around the number of threads that were spawned, minus whatever threading overhead there might be.

Comment: The threading would happen inside `sort`. `sort` would join on the threads it created before returning.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis But for `sort()`, what's the point of spawning another thread if you're just going to block the original thread anyways?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Oh wait, I see what you're saying... Let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the first test the code will run in single Thread.

In the second test the code will run in multiple Threads.

```
@Test
public void shouldSortInSingleThread() {

    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    IntStream.range(0, 50000).forEach(nbr -> labels.add("str" + nbr));
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
    Arrays.sort(labels.toArray(new String[] {}), (String first,
            String second) -> {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
        return Integer.compare(first.length(), second.length());

    });

}

@Test
public void shouldSortInParallel() {

    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    IntStream.range(0, 50000).forEach(nbr -> labels.add("str" + nbr));

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
    Arrays.parallelSort(labels.toArray(new String[] {}), (String first,
            String second) -> {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
        return Integer.compare(first.length(), second.length());

    });

}
```